# Audit Trigger, Insert Blob As LongText

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create an audit trigger, inserting blob data as longtext datatype.

When I use select I see the content of the image, but when I insert using the same format it shows up as blank.

**Works**: data display the raw content of the image

```
select cast(my_image as char) as data from MyTable
```

**Doesn't Work**: data column appears blank (0byte)

```
insert into MyAuditTable (data) values ( cast(NEW.my_image as char) )
```

**Update: Sep. 12**
I tried to put it through a function hoping by explicitly specify the type then it will take, but no luck there either

```
CREATE FUNCTION `BLOB2TXT`(dablob LONGBLOB) RETURNS LONGTEXT 
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
       RETURN CAST(dablob AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8); 
END
```

I published my project on github if anyone want to take a look or want to use what I have. You are always welcome :)

https://github.com/hotmit/mysql-sp-audit

Right now the only thing that give me some hope is Hex(blob) but when I UNHEX() the data is not readable.

Comment: have you try it with CONVERT()?

Comment: I tried cast, convert, insert as is. All of them end up as blank.

Comment: please clarify which table represents MyTable and which fields are date, my_image in your github project ?  what file to look in ?

Comment: "MyTable" is just a test table, it does not exist in my github project. Basically I want to convert an image and store it it zaudit_meta's old_value column.

Comment: @DuD. - i just saw your github repo before seeing this post. tried it and is working as intended. thank you very much for your time. starred your repo too!

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
INSERT INTO zaudit_meta(audit_id, col_name)
SELECT 0
    ,CAST(my_image AS CHAR)
```

If your `SELECT` query works correctly, this solution should work.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Joël, I tried that and I still gets an emptied varchar field.

Comment: @DuD. Can you confirm that if you remove the INSERT statement of my query, you've the desired result?

Comment: Joël, when I just use the select it display the content as expected.

Comment: @DuD. It's very strange. Can you just confirm me that you have no error when you run my query

Comment: @DuD. Can you try to replace my `CAST` statement by a hard-coded `CHAR` value and tell me if the insertion is correctly done? If not, it'll be useful to provide the structure of your table `MyAuditTable` and the active constraints on it.

Comment: Joël, you can go here https://github.com/hotmit/mysql-sp-audit/blob/master/dev/tbl_zaudit.sql to see the structure, the table I'm try to insert into is zaudit_meta. The insert work when I insert using your syntax like this: 

INSERT INTO zaudit_meta (audit_id, col_name, old_value)
SELECT 0, 'col', 'hello';

Comment: @DuD. Thank you for the structure, I see that in your table [zaudit_meta] there are two required columns: `audit_id` and `col_name`. I suppose that you're trying to insert the casted image into `col_name`, but have you already provided a value for `audit_id` during your test?

Comment: Joël, I did provide audit_id and col_name, please see my previous comment.

Comment: @DuD. I'm looking your table structure and i have another question that may help to isolate the problem. Why are you casting your image into `CHAR` when the target column `col_name` is of type `VARCHAR(255)`? And second question, did you try a `SELECT` statement with the casting you've tested in your function `BLOB2TEXT`?

Comment: Joël, col_name is the name of the column therefore it's varchar and the blob is the value of the column. I did try blob2text method with a select and result is the same.

Comment: @DuD.Are you sure that the result of your casting is less than 255 characters??

Comment: Joël, col_name is for storing the column name therefore it would be over 255 length. The column I'm try to place the blob in is "old_value" and "new_value". They are longtext datafield so the length is not an issue.

Comment: @DuD. Based on your GitHub project, the column `new_value` is not `LONGTEXT` but `NVARCHAR(255)`!